# IIS: How to test Web Server banners?

Tags: iis

How can I test a web server banner?

I have made changes to the HTTP Header Tab in IIS and need to verify that it is not displaying the Version in the banner.. ie; `X-Powered-By; ASP.NET`

Answer (score 3):

You can view the header here: http://web-sniffer.net/

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor traffic to/from the web pages/services that I'm developing. It lets you see what is being submitted and returned, headers and bodies.